# Cannot apply expression of type to a visible type argument when using Data.Proxy?

Tags: haskell

In one of my modules where I have the let expression:

```
let persist = mkCassEntityPersist (Proxy @SxRecord) cassCliSt
```

This gives an error:

```
    • Cannot apply expression of type ‘t1’
      to a visible type argument ‘SxRecord’
    • In the first argument of ‘mkCassEntityPersist’, namely
        ‘(Proxy @SxRecord)’
      In the expression: mkCassEntityPersist (Proxy @SxRecord) cassCliSt
      In an equation for ‘persist’:
          persist = mkCassEntityPersist (Proxy @SxRecord) cassCliSt
   |
43 |   let persist = mkCassEntityPersist (Proxy @SxRecord) cassCliSt
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, in another module, with a subset of the GHC language extensions used in the first, I am perfectly ok to do this:

```
recTypeRep :: TypeRep
recTypeRep = typeRep $ Proxy @SxRecord
```

Is there a way to address the issue? 
The meaning of the error message is not that clear to me either at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case, an `import Data.Proxy` had been forgotten.